# nginx block not getting triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this file:

`.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/rewrite.config`

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/rewrite.config":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      location / {
          error_log "Rewrite rule triggered for URL: $uri" info;
          rewrite ^([^#]*)%23(.*)$ $1#$2 permanent;
      }
```

When I deploy this to Elastic Beanstalk using `eb deploy`, then make requests to the web app, this part is not triggered.

Is the code above correct? What am I doing wrong?

Note: Purpose of code is to replace %23 with #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have discovered yesterday and ended up working for me.

Create this file:

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
```

This way you can override the default `/` block. Other solutions didn't work.

Hope this helps me and other people in the future!

Answer (score 1):

If your environment is based on a platform built on top of the AWS AMI 2 image, put your nginx config in this directory :

*.platform/nginx/conf.d/rewrite.conf*

[More info here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

Comment: Indeed, I figured out this yesterday. AWS has changed this a few times, but the internet is still confused about it. Thank you